# sudo chown command fails to give ownership to user account

Tags: command-line, permissions, mount, chmod, chown

I have tried running:

```
sudo chown dendy /mnt/storage1/
```

which returns:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/storage1/': Operation not permitted
```

I have also tried:

```
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/storage1/
```

which does not return any errors, however, when I check the folder permissions, it still shows root for the owner and group.

What can I do to allow my user, "dendy", to be able to write files to and read from these directories?

Comment: What format is storage1? Post this: `sudo parted -l`. If NTFS or FAT32, then Windows formats do not support Linux ownership & permissions. Those are set for entire partition by how you mount partition.

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Comment: Well, the full output seems to exceed the maximum character length for a reply by a few thousand characters but I do see most of these drives are ntfs although I do have some that are just blank for that section. Am I able to mount them differently? I was able to write to them previously and I haven't changed the formatting of these external drives.

Comment: @Dendy You can always post the output as an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1356608/edit).